# How do you convert from UnsafeArray<CFloat> to Array<Float> in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Some Cocoa classes, for example AVFoundation's `AVAudioPCMBuffer` deal in arrays of floating point data, which are exposed in Objective-C using type `float *`.

For example the Objective-C prototype for `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) float *const *floatChannelData
```

The Swift equivalent is:

```
var floatChannelData: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<CFloat>> { get }
```

The inner `UnsafePointer<>` can be unpacked to an `UnsafeArray<CFloat>` using `UnsafeArray()`, but how can this then be converted to a regular Swift `Array<Float>`?

I could just iterate over each Float, copying each one to a new Array, but this is expensive and not really feasible for large arrays.

Answer (score 3):

A Swift array is wrapped in an opaque struct, which has a different layout and memory management than an arbitrary C float[] array.  So you either have to copy the data if you want to use native Swift Array syntax on it, or pass an UnsafePointer into the Swift array (which is already wrapped in the proper Swift struct) to the C or Objective C API, and use that when you get data back.